# How can I get all hasgtags in a string into an array?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, hashtag

I need get the hash tags from the user input as an array.

Input:

```
$str = "hello#new #test #again"
```

Expected output:

```
Array ( [0] => new [1] => test [2] => again )
```

I have tried this code, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
function convertHashtags($str){
    $regex = "/#+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/";
    $str = preg_replace($regex, '<a href="hashtag.php?tag=$1">$0</a>', $str);
    return($str);    
}

$string = "hello#new #test #again";
$string = convertHashtags($string);
```

Instead of replace I need `$string` with the tags as array.

Comment: Why is `hello` an expected part of your resultant array? It's not a hash tag.

Comment: If hello is not a hash, the code in question works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

First replace all `#` with a space with [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). Then you can simply split it into an array with [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) on 1 or more spaces (`\s+`).

```
<?php

    $string = "hello#new #test #again";
    $tags = preg_split("/\s+/", str_replace("#", " ", $string));

    print_r($tags);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => new
    [2] => test
    [3] => again
)
```

**EDIT:**

And if you only want the words after a hashtag in the array, just use this:

```
<?php

    $string = "hello#new#test #again";
    preg_match_all("/#(\w+)/", $string, $m);

    print_r($m[1]);

?>
```

regex explanation:

```
#(\w+)
```

- **#** matches the character # literally
- **\w+** match any word character **[a-zA-Z0-9_]**

  - Quantifier: **+** Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

Comment: I don't want hello only words with hash is needed

Comment: @shammon In your question you want it in the array and now not?!

Comment: Sorry its my mistake,i only need hashed words

Comment: @Shammon Then edit your question, you currently have `hello` in the expected output, remove it if you don't want it, the answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: @shammon updated my answer, so that you only have hashtag words in your array.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
(#\S+)
```

---

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/qZ3hB7/3)

Explaining:

`(            ' start of capturing-group
    #         ' matches a sharp, meaning a new variable
    \S+       ' anything until next space
)             ' and of capturing-group saving`

Hope it helps.

Comment: OP don't want `hello` in his array anymore: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31697131/3933332 Maybe you want to update your answer.

Comment: @Rizier123. Thank you for that. Updated

Answer (score 0):

Why use RegEx, if it's not necessary??

You can use `explode()` as long as you only want to split the string at `#`

```
$result = $explode('#',$string);
```

If you want to get rid of the  in the strings use this aswell:

```
foreach($result as $entrie){
  $entrie = trim($entrie):
}
```

That should solve your problem without the need to use RegEx.

**EDIT**

For the part with the first Element has no `#` you can use this to deal with it:

```
if(strpos($string,'#') === 0)unset($result[0]);
```

That removes the first entrie if the first char in the string is not `#`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is this

```
 $string = "hello#new #test #again";
 $result = explode('#',$string);
 array_shift($result);
 print_R($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$list = []; 
$string = "hey hello #new #test #again"; 
$result = explode(' ',$string); 
foreach($result as $res) if (starts_with($res, '#')) $list[]=$res; 
print_r($list);
```

Comment: How about formatting this piece of code properly so it can be evaluated?

Comment: @localheinz i dont understand